# How to restrict height of Google responsive Ads?

Tags: html, css, adsense

I want to make a responsive ad that is limited to 90-250px height and 250-1280px width on the desktop.

So, I looked at the [official Google documentation](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183363#exact&zippy=%2Cexact-size-per-screen-width-example%2Cexpandable-width-with-fixed-height-example) and created the ad code as follows.

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
   style="display:inline-block;min-height:90px;max-height:250px;min-width:250px;max-width:1280px;width:100%;height:100%"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000"
   data-ad-slot="000"></ins>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-000" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

However, with this code, only 90px x 1280px ads are displayed.

So I back to responsive ad and added a class to the ad to limit the height.

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle testad"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-333"
     data-ad-slot="333"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>


.testad{
max-height:250px !important;
}
```

In this case, Google Ads override the height limit.

Ads with width:100%, height:280px will be displayed.

Could someone tell me which part I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try something along these lines.  So standard size is 90px but when the screen is minimum of 1280px, use the large one.  Hopefully you know how to tidy it up to your liking.

```
<style>
.adsiz { width:90px; height: 250px; }
@@media screen and (width:1280px) { width:1280px; height:250px}
</style>

<div class="adsiz">
<ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000"data-ad-slot="000">/ins></div>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-000" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```